# dropdown menu on flexdashboard element?

Tags: r, dropdown, flexdashboard

Is there a way to add a dropdown menu to one element on flexdashboard so that the user can pick which table is shown? In this example I have 3 small tables, one for each species, but i would like to only show one table at the time, and to be able to change which one is shown using the dropdown menu. I tried using tabs, but there is another table which should be shown in the column at all times, and couldn't find the way around that.
thank you very much!

````
---
title: "Titulo"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)

```

Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Small table 1

```{r, echo=FALSE}

iris %>% filter(Species=="setosa")

```


### Small table 2

```{r,echo=FALSE}

iris %>% filter(Species=="virginica")

```


### Small table 3

```{r, echo=FALSE}

iris %>% filter(Species=="versicolor")

```

### Not related table

```{r, echo=FALSE}

cars

```

Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### BIG PLOT

```{r}

plot(cars, pch = 20)

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `flexdashboard` is not very helpful, but looking at the [examples](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/tree/main/inst/examples) it would seem that including `runtime: shiny` on the header will let you get away with using any `shiny` input and render functions:

````
---
title: "Titulo"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime:
  shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
```

Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Small table 

```{r, echo=FALSE}
selectInput("small_table", "Table to show:",
            c("setosa","virginica","versicolor"))
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderTable(
  iris %>% filter(Species == input$small_table)
)
```

### Not related table

```{r, echo=FALSE}
cars
```

Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### BIG PLOT

```{r}
plot(cars, pch = 20)
```
````